# Using Linq to create a collection of a custom class from a DbSet that contains a list of grouped entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework, collections

## Given a data set which looks something like:

```
Iqueryable<photos> which represents the following table in a database

DataTable table = new DataTable("Trip");
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("PhotoName", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add("1/1/2001", "Home", "Photo1.jpg");
table.Rows.Add("1/1/2001", "Home", "Photo2.jpg");
table.Rows.Add("1/2/2001", "Work", "Photo3.jpg");
table.Rows.Add("1/2/2001", "Work", "Photo4.jpg");
table.Rows.Add("1/3/2001", "Home", "Photo5.jpg");
```

## I want to create a collection of the following class which is grouped by Date & Location:

```
 class PhotoCollection
 { 
      string date;
      string location;
      IList<string> namesOfPhotos;
 }
```

## I started with:

```
 from photo in photos
 group photo by new { photo.date, photo.location };
```

## Question:

Now that the items are grouped is it possible to neatly create a collection of PhotoCollection inline?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
var result = from photo in photos
             group photo by new { date, location } into grp
             select new PhotoCollection {
                                         date = grp.Key.date,
                                         location = grp.Key.location,
                                         namesOfPhotos = grp.Select(p => p.PhotoName).ToList()
                                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<PhotoCollection> lst = 
              from t in table.AsEnumerable()
              group t by new { t.Field<string>("Location"), t.Field<string>("Date") }
              into g
              select new PhotoCollection
              {
                 date = g.Key.Date,
                 location = g.Key.Location,
                 namesOfPhotos = g.Select(c => c.Field<string>("PhotoName")).ToList()
              }
```

For more info on how to query a datatable with linq, look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx)